# Невозможно прописать fx:id в FXML файле

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Такая проблема:

есть fxml-файл с таким кодом

```
 <TextField fx:id="txtField" alignment="TOP_LEFT" onAction="#getNumberFromTF" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="54.0" />
```

и соответственно контроллер следующего содержания:
@FXML private TextField txtField;

```
@FXML
private void getNumberFromTF() {
    try {
        txtField.addActionListener((ae) ->
                MainApp.numberPage = Integer.parseInt(txtField.getText()));
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Почему в fxml-файле fx:id выделено красным?
При наведении на fx:id курсором, IDEA показывает сообщение:
"Cannot set javafx.scene.control.TextField to field 'txtField' "

**Перенесено из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718657/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-fxid-%D0%B2-fxml-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B5#comment1081251_718660):** Проблема решена, был импорт из библиотеки awt, а надо из javafx

Answer (score 0):

У вас в контроллере должно быть написано следующее

```
public TextField txtField;
```

или

```
@Fxml
private TextField txtField;
```

И скорее всего, у вас так не написано.

Comment: написано все, в том то и дело. Посмотрите внимательнее на код в строке после слова "содержания:", код почему-то не попал в блок кода...

Comment: приведите тогда пример, как у вас объявлено в контроллере, вместе с импортами

Comment: Плюс у вас метод getNumberFromTF должен принимать в качестве параметров ActionEvent

Comment: Проблема решена, был импорт из библиотеки awt, а надо из javafx!

Comment: А как тогда буде выглядеть метод  getNumberFromTF , если он должен принимать ActionEvent

Comment: public void getNumberFromTF(javafx.event.ActionEvent event)